# Find items that aren't in a many to many relationship in Django

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have some models, where Books can have many Authors and vice versa:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=140)

class Author(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book, related_name="authors")
```

I need to find all Books that have no author from a `Book` queryset, yet I can't find an appropriate `.filter()` or `.exclude()` clause that will do it.

Can I do this from a queryset?

Comment: Do you know how to write it using SQL?

Comment: No actually, I don't :(

Answer (score 2):

You can simply write

```
Book.objects.filter(author_set=None)
```

or, if you have an existing query

```
book_queryset.filter(author_set=None)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :)

Comment: Note to readers: this used to be the accepted answer, until OP ragequit and attempted to punish bystanders for their [political disagreement with Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342994) in the process. Feel free to throw it an upvote to compensate if you like ;-)